# How to call method with PaintEventArgs from KeyDown method

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm learning Form Applications and very new to the whole way of how this works. I want to paint something on the screen (line) on user key press, but I can't figure out how to parse the PaintEventArgs to the method. I've read different post, but I do not understand what I'm actually supposed to do. Most of the say use `PictureBox` tried a few things, but cant call the paint from `KeyDown` Method.

I have also added my `KeyDown` method inside the `InitializeComponent`.

`this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);`

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs ke)
{
    if (ke.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
    {
        Custom_Paint(sender, needPaintEventArgsHere);
    }
}

private void Custom_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);

    pe.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 200.0F, 400.0F, 500.0F, 700.0F);
}
```

Comment: What's the point of this: `Graphics g = pe.Graphics; //[...] pe.Graphics.DrawLine(...)`? That assignment is completely useless. You either use `pe.Graphics` or assign it to use a *shorter version*, so you can write, i.e., `g.DrawLine(...)` instead of `pe.Graphics.DrawLine(...)`, so you have less stuff to write (the only reason for this assignment - though you can simply copy/paste it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inherit from the `Form` class, you don't need to subscribe the events such as `KeyDown`, `KeyUp` or `Paint`. Instead, you should override the corresponding methods `OnKeyDown`, `OnKeyUp`, `OnPaint`. In your case, you should write your draw logic inside the overriden `OnPaint` method and draw directly on the `Graphics` object passed through `PaintEventArgs.Graphics`. After that, when you need a repaint, just call `Control.Invalidate` to trigger the `OnPaint` method.

Also, you might want to enable double-buffering for your `Form` as shown in the constructor.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
   private bool m_isSpaceKeyPressed = false;
   public Form1()
   {
       SetStyle(ControlStyle.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
       InitializeComponent();
   }
   protected override void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnPaint(e);
       if(!m_isSpaceKeyPressed)
          return;
       Graphics g = e.Graphics;
       Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);

       g.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 200.0F, 400.0F, 500.0F, 700.0F);
   }
   protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
       {
           m_isSpaceKeyPressed = true;
           Invalidate();
       }
   }
   protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
       {
           m_isSpaceKeyPressed = false;
           Invalidate();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but is it possible to not draw to begin with and only draw on keypress? I will accept your answer tho and hope to hear soon.

Comment: You have to draw that line. If you want to draw it on a condition, then add, e.g., a bool Field (say `bool drawIt = false;`) and set it to `true` when a key is pressed. The first line in the `OnPaint()` override can then be `base.OnPaint(e); if (!drawIt) return; // Drawing code...`

Comment: Thanks, you've opened my eyes a lot to a few key things. Much Appreciated.